# How do I wrap several buttons inside a TD element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to alter this collection of buttons to wrap at the right edge of the screen.  Currently they do not respect the right border of the screen and they just continue off the edge (well they aren't visible anyway).
How do I force these buttons to automatically wrap to a new line within the table? The screen is re-sizable so I can't just set them statically.

Thanks.

```
<td>    
<table class="clsActionTable">
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
            <button class="clsActionButton" id="idAddButton" onclick="idAddButton_onclick();">Add</button>
            <button class="clsActionButton" id="idEditButton" onclick="idEditButton_onclick();">Edit</button>
            <button class="clsActionButton" id="idDeleteButton" onclick="idDeleteButton_onclick();">Delete</button>
            <button class="clsActionButton" id="idManageRowButton" onclick="idManageRowButton_onclick();">Add Row</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and the CSS...

```
.clsActionTable
{
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    font-size: smaller;
}

.clsActionButton
{
    width: 128px;
}
#idActionPlane
{
left: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
width:100%;
background-color: #4E5A81;
color: White;
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide any relevant CSS?  This should wrap.

Comment: updated w/ CSS.  Maybe the fixed widths are preventing the wrap?

Comment: This should still wrap  http://jsfiddle.net/jVXMy/  it seems this table is nested within another table.  Perhaps it is that outer table.

Comment: Well, there IS a sibling table, and they are indeed both inside of a parent table (sorry, its legacy code).  The parent definitions ... <div id="idActionPlane" style="postion=absolute;">
  <table style="width:100%;height:30px">

Comment: Sorry, still not seeing it wrap.  Which browser are you using?  http://jsfiddle.net/jVXMy/1/

Comment: The app hosts IE.  I have IE9 at the moment.

Comment: Does the fiddle wrap for you?  If not, if you can reproduce the problem in the fiddle I can probably help.  Other than that, it seems to work as is.

Comment: @bob: The reason you are not seeing it wrap in IE9 is because http://jsfiddle.net/jVXMy/1/ automatically drops into compatibility mode. If you un-check it and put it back to standards mode you will see it wrap. It wraps for IE8+9 but not IE7.

Comment: @tw16 wins the prize (sorry prize is not actual).  Running kingjiv's jsfiddle code in Standards mode in IE9 DOES wrap properly.  Ironically the two versions of IE that we were going to support for this release were IE7 (for legacy compat.) and IE9 in compatibility mode.  :)  Guess I need to find an entirely different way to present these buttons. Thanks all.

Comment: @bob: So was mine the correct answer? If so I will put it down below in the answers and you can accept it.

Comment: @tw16 Yeah, I think so.  I still don't know how to refactor this so that it WILL wrap when hosted in IE7.  I think I need to get rid of that table, so if you have any insight into the original problem (how to make these buttons wrap), that would be appreciated.

Comment: @bob: I have updated my answer below so that it will wrap in IE7 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are not seeing it wrap in IE9 is because your original code http://jsfiddle.net/VdBGe/ automatically drops into compatibility mode. If you un-check it and put it back to standards mode you will see it wrap. It wraps for IE8+9 but not IE7.

To make it wrap in IE7 using your original code, you need to wrap the buttons in a `div` and set `width:100%`. Live Example: http://jsfiddle.net/VdBGe/1/

**HTML:**

```
<td style="text-align:center;">
    <div id="btnwrap">
        <button class="clsActionButton" id="idAddButton" onclick="idAddButton_onclick();">Add</button>
        <button class="clsActionButton" id="idEditButton" onclick="idEditButton_onclick();">Edit</button>
        <button class="clsActionButton" id="idDeleteButton" onclick="idDeleteButton_onclick();">Delete</button>
        <button class="clsActionButton" id="idManageRowButton" onclick="idManageRowButton_onclick();">Add Row</button>
    </div>
</td>
```

**CSS:**

```
#btnwrap{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <table class="clsActionTable">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center;">
                <button class="clsActionButton moveright" id="idAddButton" onclick="idAddButton_onclick();">Add</button>

                <button class="clsActionButton moveright" id="idEditButton" onclick="idEditButton_onclick();">Edit</button>

                <button class="clsActionButton moveright" id="idDeleteButton" onclick="idDeleteButton_onclick();">Delete</button>

                <button class="clsActionButton moveright" id="idManageRowButton" onclick="idManageRowButton_onclick();">Add Row</button>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

and the css

```
.moveright {
    float: right;
}


.clearfix:after {
   content:"\0020";
   display:block;
   height:0;
   clear:both;
   visibility:hidden;
   overflow:hidden;
}
.clearfix{display:block;}
```

Comment: That seems to be putting each button on a new line, correct?  I only want it to do so if there is not room on the current line for another button, and it needs to be resizable.

Comment: Ok. I've modified the html by removing the "<div class='clearfix'></div>'.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these buttons are floating & display block. I recommend the following.

1. you remove text-align:center from the `<td>`
2. remove both float and display: block from the buttons(If they have these properties)
3. To align them right, just give the  text align-right

Hope this makes sense

Comment: sorry, no dice.  And there were neither float nor display style properties present.

Comment: What about removing that width on .clsActionTable. Also, what if you make the buttons hrefs?

Comment: Removed the clsActionTable, nothing there.  If I change the buttons to href they do appear to wrap.  If I wrap the buttons WITH href elements they go back to not wrapping.  There could be a solution in there.